# jvm / scala / lift application stack?

Tags: eclipse, scala, lift

After some research before decision making, decided to start a heavy comet based project on Scala's Lift.

What's a recommended application stack for lift on scala?

I'm leaning towards:
Jetty / (DB ? (Postgre/Mysql ?) / Scala / Lift / SBT / (Eclipse as IDE )

I'm probably going to be developing on Windows and deploying on Ubuntu Server, so what would be a recommended way to start off.

I'm thinking of: Install full Java SDK (do I need J2EE ? ) , then JEtty, Scala, Lift, SBT, then Eclipse with the Scala plugin (should I be looking into IntelliJ or Netbeans ? )

Anything I need to keep in mind?

Comment: Why develop on Windows if you intend to deploy on Ubuntu?

Comment: 1- Have used Linux and Solaris as server environments for a long time now, but Windows as a desktop environment (Mac only for iPhone development) for that same time. Used to it by now.
2- Not sure if Adobe suite is available in Linux, and also other Windows only programs such as EMS or Visual Studio for the .NET projects
3- Virtual env are usually pretty lagging to use as desktop environments 

All that said though, if after setting up both envs (Windows and UbuntuSVR) there are issues then I'm open to use Linux for dev as well. Think all should be fine tho, since everything uses the jvm

Comment: @REX Kerr ... was trying to edit my comment and couldn't so removed it and re-entered ... sorry about it

Comment: (copying my previous answer and adding): Ah, okay. If you're making heavy use of Adobe's Creative Suite, you're right, you're better off in Windows. I was going to suggest that the testing cycle would be easier with everything on the same machine, but not if you're making heavy use of Adobe's tools.  I don't really like the VM solution either for desktops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the IntelliJ Scala plugin is a lot more useful than the Eclipse one. Since Martin Odersky recently started work on the Eclipse plugin it is expected that soon it will be greatly improved, but at this point there are only beta version of the new plugin(and they are not particularly stable).

SBT is going a lot of internal changes right now(the new 0.9 version is nothing like 0.7.x) and doesn't integrate very well with IDEs currenty - most SBT IDE plugins are quite basic at this point so I sometimes prefer to use Maven 3 with the Scala plugin or generate native IDE projects for Eclipse/IntelliJ with an SBT plugin.

If you decided to stick with SBT I recommend you to have a look at [Lifty](http://lifty.github.com/Lifty/) as well. Other than that your stack seems to be completely adequate.

One sidenote - when you start developing the project ignore older tutorials that don't use [Designer Friendly Templates](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Designer_Friendly_Templates) and [css selectors](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-7.10.html)(in other words don't use bind). [Simply Lift](http://simply.liftweb.net/) and Lift in Action both describe these newer(and arguably better) techniques.

Comment: I actually found the betas of the new plugin better than the so called 'stable' of the older version. If you go eclipse I'd go with the new plugin and helios.

Comment: I concur with your statement. I was merely saying the the betas are unstable in comparison to something like the IntelliJ plugin which is quite feature rich and mature.

Comment: IntelliJ scala plugin is not stable or mature. Every other release, basic stuff like @BeanProperty breaks.. only to remain broken for 2 months before getting fixed. (overall intelliJ maven integration is much nicer than eclipse, but scala is kind of spotty in both)

Comment: I notice problems from time to time as well, but I think this is normal with any rapidly evolving piece of software. IntelliJ recently committed much more resources to the plugin and thing became a bit crazy, but if you look at the features that were implemented - their code analyser even features Scala style checks... Java code is converted to Scala code on paste, the refactorings just work. The only buggy thing is the type-aware analyser, but it is currently in beta anyways...